# How can I convert some data in TableForm to a list form like as {{0,1}, {1,2},{...,...},...,{m,n}}?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I convert some data in TableForm to a list form like as 
So, I have some data there I take from laboratory, but the data has a TableForm

0.0 0.2174

1e-06   0.2178

2e-06   0.2172

3e-06   0.217

but, I want to put it in list form, for example

{{0.0,0.2174}, {1e-6,0.2178},{2e-6,0.2172},{3e-06,0.217}}

Thank You

Comment: how is the data imported? there are many options for a file import- if it is copy paste, putting in a txt file first would allow access to these import options

Comment: @PeterRoberge I forgot to say, it is just an .txt archive. I think it is in Tab separated form

Comment: Import["text.txt","Table"]

Comment: @PeterRoberge  Yes, it worked! it was just it I needed! Thank you so much!